# How to format XML in POST body for an asp.net WebAPI POST route

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net WebAPI RESTful service, where I have a POST endpoint for GPS positions.

The server controller has the following route:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostGpsPositions(GpsPositionsModel positions)
```

The body classes are as follows:

```
 public class GpsPositionsModel 
  {
    [Required]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
 
    [Required]
    public List<GPSData> Positions { get; set; } 
 }
 
  public class GPSData 
  {       
    [Required]
    public double X { get; set; }
   
    [Required]
    public double Y { get; set; }
   
    [Required]
    public double Z { get; set; }    
  }
```

I always just use `json`, but someone has asked me if they can submit the body in `XML`.

It appears this should be possible, by including the `Content-Type:"application/xml"` header.

I would have thought the format would look like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <GpsPositionsModel>
      <SenderId>1</SenderId>
      <Positions>
        <GPSData>
            <x>1.1</x>
            <y>1.1</y>
            <z>1.1</z>
        </GPSData>    
      </Positions>
    </GpsPositionsModel>
```

But this just did not work, I get back `400 Bad Request`.

I have a validating filter on the server:

```
ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
```

and in the `OnActionExecuting` I can see it does have the XML content header, but  the model state is false:

[image]

So, my question is how should the XML be formatted here? Do I need `ArrayOf` somewhere in the structure, and if so how do I apply this to the list I am sending?

### Update

Added attributes as suggested in comments.

So server side I have:

```
    namespace Models.Common
    {
      [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace.com")]
      public class GpsPositionsModel
      {
        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public int SenderId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public List<GPSData> Positions { get; set; }
      }

      [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace.com")]
      public class GPSData
      {
        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public double X { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public double Z { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("gps")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SubmitGpsData([FromBody]GpsPositionsModel gpsData)
    {      
      return new HttpResponseMessage();
    }
```

And using Postman, I call using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <GpsPositionsModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/http://mynamespace.com">
      <SenderId>1</SenderId>
      <Positions>
           <GPSData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/http://mynamespace.com">
                        <x>1.1</x>
                        <y>1.1</y>
                        <z>1.1</z>                          
           </GPSData>
        <GPSData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/http://mynamespace.com">
                        <x>1.1</x>
                        <y>1.1</y>
                        <z>1.1</z>                          
           </GPSData>
      </Positions>
    </GpsPositionsModel>
```

And in Postman console I get:

[image]

I am using WebAPI2, asp.net full framework

```
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net47" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For posting xml you need to specify the xmlns in the format:
`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace`

So in your case you need to post xml like this:

```
<GpsPositionsModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/{namespance containing GpsPositionsModel class}">
    <Positions>
        <GPSData>
            <X>1</X>
            <Y>1</Y>
            <Z>2</Z>
        </GPSData>
    </Positions>
    <SenderId>1</SenderId>
    </GpsPositionsModel>
```

In case the GpsPositionsModel class in not inside any namespace you can leave it empty like:
`xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names

Comment: Thanks @Mohsin, but unfortunately this did not make any difference, The above does look more like what you do for WCF, but I tried it anyway (including the namespace)

Comment: Can you share updated xml schema with namespace? I tested it on my end it worked. I am assuming you’re using Asp.WebApi 2. Also which .Net Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter in the action method

`public HttpResponseMessage PostGpsPositions([FromBody]GpsPositionsModel positions)`

Also, to the model

add `[DataContract]` over the class name and `[DataMember]` over each of the properties in the model

Comment: Thanks @akg179, but unfortunately this did not make any difference, The above does look more like what you do for WCF, but I tried it anyway.